# my website is coming up blank/white but source is there

Tags: html

Not sure what happened. 
I installed phpBB on a subdomain via the quickinstaller in cpanel.

http://forum.guruvix.com

but now my main site is coming up as a blank page, but the source code is there and there is a scroll bar indicating that content should be show but it is not... any ideas?

Site that is blank is 
http://www.guruvix.com

Comment: And that's the reason you should use debugging tools like firebug

Comment: @Mr. Alien There are no errors in the console, because the javascript is commented out.

Comment: @remyabel Console is not what am talking about, you can also debug your CSS and tweak HTML there

Comment: @Mr. Alien Indeed, I was just pointing out that I thought it was weird that there were no errors in the console, since that would seem to point out the culprit for why the offending CSS/HTML isn't removed by the script.

Comment: @Mr. Alien Although firebug -is- useful for the end user. It is trivial nowadays to remove annoying pop-ups, greyed-out areas, modal dialogs, etc. without loss of functionality of the rest of the site. But I'm assuming OP likes his fancy loading screen.

Comment: @remyabel even I used to have those loading screens in my portfolio, at the end, I removed it cuz it was kinda frustrating for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your javascript is commented out in the HTML.

```
         <!--
<script _wpro_type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tweet.js" _wpro_src="js/jquery.tweet.js" type="text/wpro"></script>--&gt;
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.queryloader2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>

etc...

--&gt;
-->
```

In particular the code you want to execute is located in `js/scripts.js`:

```
// BEGIN WINDOW.LOAD FUNCTION       
$(window).load(function(){

    $('#load').fadeOut().remove(); // <----- 
    $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
    $(window).trigger( 'resize' );
  $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
    var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh');

  });
```

`#load` is styled to take up the entire page and appear white. Aka why your page appears 'blank'. The solution is either to remove `<div id="load"></div>` from the HTML file, or to uncomment your `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="load"></div>
```

Which has CSS of

```
body #load {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 1001;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Is hiding your content